# ng-bootstrap ngbDatepicker sets form as invalid if changing from a date to null

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap's ngbDatepicker in an Angular application to support a non-required date field, but if the field comes in with a date, setting the date to null will result in the field/form being marked as invalid.

Using the code below, if `note.expires_on` initially has a date and is then set to null, the form is marked invalid:

`<input name="expires_on" [(ngModel)]="note.expires_on" ngbDatepicker #datePicker="ngbDatepicker">`

I see from the post below that if the date is initialized as null, then a null value will not result in an invalid form, but in my case, initializing as null doesn't seem like an option.

[How to mark ngbDatepicker Valid in form even when no value is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828287/how-to-mark-ngbdatepicker-valid-in-form-even-when-no-value-is-selected?newreg=7065f041f79444ceb67a041c4f809c17)

Comment: Can't reproduce, check this plunker where things seems to be working perfectly fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/bdque81d3BO1ZcsoDhc0?p=preview. Please update your question with a modified plunker that actually reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the prompt response.

On the plunker you posted, if you highlight the date, hit delete and then enter, the form is marked as invalid, as `model` is then set to empty string.

I created a plunker having a `onChangeDate` method that explicitly sets `model` to null, which seems to fix this issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/mjaNQK0nViVRyKd39kGu?p=preview