# Required DatePicker in reactive form

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I have a reactive form with Datepicker

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label class="form-control-label" for="field_dataAtivacao">Data Ativação</label>
     <div class="input-group">
         <input id="field_dataAtivacao" type="text" class="form-control" name="dataAtivacao" ngbDatepicker #dataAtivacaoDp="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="dataAtivacao"/>
         <span class="input-group-append">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="dataAtivacaoDp.toggle()">
                 <fa-icon [icon]="'calendar-alt'"></fa-icon>
             </button>
         </span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Form control without validator

```
editForm = this.fb.group({
    dataAtivacao: null,
});
```

The field is empty but always is required. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873433/5360385) but without success

**EDIT**

The above example works normally when I don't use the patch value method to update the form.

Like this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grybsk?file=app/datepicker-basic.html) of the comments

The problem occurs when I need to update the form using the `patchValue` method.

```
this.editForm.patchValue({
    dataAtivacao: cliente.dataAtivacao,
});
```

When I change for `null` works normally but I need to show the date and allows update the form with the current selected

```
this.editForm.patchValue({
        dataAtivacao: null,
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grybsk-vrnclb

Comment: Your code should work perfectly fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grybsk?file=app/datepicker-basic.html Please provide a [mcve]. **Please also note to not use `ngModel` with formcontrol**. In my stackblitz it doesn't seem to cause any issue, but maybe on your end.

Comment: I've identified the problem. It occurs when I use the patchValue method of form group. I will edit the question

Comment: So fork my stackblitz to showcase the issue. I don't understand why patchValue would cause such an issue?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grybsk-vrnclb

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
editForm = this.fb.group({
    dataAtivacao : ["", Validators.required]
})
```

Comment: Have you import ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: @renanzin check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-date-picker-custom-date-format. Is it helpful. It is with custom date format also